# How to get an App Role's value with GRAPH API in Java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using GRAPH API via an application to connect to an AZURE AD. I am able to pull users/groups/roles. I can even pull app roles. However I need to be able to access the app roles value within my code and cannot figure out how to do so.

```
    AppRoleAssignmentCollectionPage appRoleAssignments = graphClient.users(userId).appRoleAssignments()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();

        List<AppRoleAssignment> memberRolesCurrentPage = appRoleAssignments.getCurrentPage();
        if (memberRolesCurrentPage.isEmpty()) {
            LOG.info("No app roles found for user");
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(AppRoleAssignment role : memberRolesCurrentPage) {
                roles.add(role.principalDisplayName);
                LOG.info( "ROLE: " + role.resourceDisplayName );
          }
```

This is one way I am pulling data, but doing role."value" doesn't work and I can't figure out a way to get that data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are already using below code at the starting of the code.
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

Here is an example of the request to retrieve the app roles that have been assigned to a user.
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

AppRoleAssignmentCollectionPage appRoleAssignments = graphClient.users("cdb555e3-b33e-4fd5-a427-17fadacbdfa7").appRoleAssignments()
.buildRequest()
.get();

Comment: Correct, I am doing all of this, however when trying to extract the "value" data there is not property or getter for it.

Comment: I believe you were not getting the list of object through code List<AppRoleAssignment> memberRolesCurrentPage = appRoleAssignments.getCurrentPage(); you can try by check by what value you got from memberRolesCurrentPage . the best way is debug your code and check values at everypoint.